# How do I dynamically create a 2D array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

So I am parsing a URL and want to get a list of all the links in a page using Nokogiri.

But I want to push the results returned into a two-dimensional array.

I am now doing this:

```
def my_list(url)
    root = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    list = []

    root.css("a").each do |link|
        list << (link[:href])           
    end

end
```

This gives me just the http links. If I do `list << link` it gives me the full `<a>` tag.

What I want to do is to push just the text of the link (can use `link.text`) to say `list[0][0]`, and then the href value (using `link[:href]`) to the other cell say `list[0][1]`.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def my_list(url)
  root = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  root.css("a").map do |link|
    [link.text, link[:href]]           
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this...pretty awesome to get it back so quick.

Answer (score 4):

```
def my_list(url)
    root = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    list = []

    root.css("a").each do |link|
        list << [link.text,link[:href]]           
    end

end
```